# What is the ratio of speed of time between Earth and Swarga Loka and Narak Loka?

Tags: time, heaven, hell

At what speed does the time move in heaven or hell with respect to earth ?  What is ratio of speed of time at these places ?

Anyone ?

Comment: Related question - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/52318/what-is-the-ratio-of-speed-of-time-between-earth-and-pitri-lok

Comment: You would need to read *Mahanirvana Tantra* to understand where such lokas exist, and how to transverse them. Alternatively, chapter - 2 of *Uttara Gita* is all about such. But again, such requires a lot of idea into tantra, Upanishads and meditation skills.